# Javascript - How come Object.create takes function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

How come newperson4 is created, and not errored? code below -

```
function person() {
}

var p = new person();
var q = null;
var r = "some string";

var newperson1 = Object.create(p); //Runs fine.
var newperson2 = Object.create(q); //Runs fine.
var newperson3 = Object.create(r); //Errors - Object.prototype requires to be an Object or Null only. Fine!
var newperson4 = Object.create(person); //Based on above error, person is a function, not an object. How is it working?
```

Comment: Functions are objects. `(function () {}) instanceof Object`. The value you get back from `Object.create(person)` isn’t very meaningful, though: you can’t call it.

Answer (score 0):

Every function is an object in javascript (like arrays are objects), not a primitive value. It can have properties, and you can inherit from it.